# What's the appropriate way of passing arguments to the static class method when it's made callable?

Tags: php, function, callback, static-methods, callable

I tried below code :

```
<?php
  class A {
    public static function who($simba) {
      echo "A\n";
      echo $simba;
    }
  }

  class B extends A {
    public static function who() {
      echo "B\n";
    }
  }
  call_user_func(array('B', 'parent::who'), $nangal="huip");
?>
```

Output :

```
Warning: Declaration of B::who() should be compatible with A::who($simba)
A huip
```

Why I'm getting this warning? I want to remove it. So, please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When overriding methods in PHP, The Overriding method signature should be compatible with parent same method! This means you should declare a `public static function who($simba)` in extended class!